# Queryset select latest record for group

Tags: python, django, oracle, orm, django-queryset

Using Django 1.65
Python 3.4.1
Oracle db

Table in the db 'Locations':

```
  location  | update_time     |  num_01   | num_02 | num_03 |
 -----------+-----------------+-----------+--------+--------
  B         | 06 Feb 18 04:14 |  42       | 43     |   55       
  C         | 22 Feb 17 04:14 |  77       | 99     |   23   
  A         | 05 Feb 18 04:14 |  48       | 43     |   21   
  A         | 01 Feb 18 04:14 |  82       | 83     |   74
```

I would like to select the row with the latest update_time for each location.

The results for the above table should be:

```
  location  | update_time     |  num_01   | num_02 | num_03 |
 -----------+-----------------+-----------+--------+--------
  A         | 05 Feb 18 04:14 |  48       | 43     |   21   
  B         | 06 Feb 18 04:14 |  42       | 43     |   55       
  C         | 22 Feb 17 04:14 |  77       | 99     |   23
```

I can use a queryset to return the latest update time for each location:

```
latest_updates = Locations.objects.values('location').annotate(max_date=Max('update_time')).order_by('location')
```

but this only returns the location and max update_time when I'm looking for the entire row - num_01, num_02, num_03.

I've spent a lot of time searching stackoverflow but nothing quite fits.
Oracle doesn't seem to support a sort by and distinct option that I can get to work.

I'm unable to import Subquery for some reason so this isn't an option for me, and I'm stuck with this version of django etc as this is at work.

The table will eventually have a reasonable amount of data in it so I'm looking for a reasonably efficient solution if possible.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
Locations.objects.order_by('location', '-update_time').distinct('location')
```

In my case it worked for Django 2.1

Comment: That doesn't work very well as for sqlite (I would have thought default db engine for tests) yields `NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`.
A bit pointless to use abstraction of database that is not portable across different supported engines.

Answer (score 5):

For Django 1.11+ you can also [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), so something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, F

qs = Location.objects.all()

# make a subquery (filter, order, get 'id')
sq = qs.filter(location=OuterRef('location')).order_by('-update_time').values('id')

# use subquery in your query (via annotation + filter)
qs.annotate(latest=Subquery(sq[:1])).filter(id=F('latest'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I found here: https://gist.github.com/ryanpitts/1304725

```
'''
given a Model with:

   category    = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
   pubdate     = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
   <other fields>

Fetch the item from each category with the latest pubdate.

''' 

model_max_set = Model.objects.values('category').annotate(max_pubdate=Max('pubdate')).order_by()

q_statement = Q()
for pair in model_max_set:
    q_statement |= (Q(category__exact=pair['category']) & Q(pubdate=pair['max_pubdate']))

model_set = Model.objects.filter(q_statement)
```

Comment: why is this best?

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
latest_updates = Locations.objects.order_by('location', '-update_time').distinct('location')
```

Comment: That would just return the max update_time of the entire table?

I want the max update_time for each location group.

Comment: "I would like to select the row with the latest update_time for each location."

Comment: I see. Please check my updated answer. See if it works for all your cases.

Comment: Thanks, that's the part about Oracle not supporting distinct on fields. Error is: 'DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend'. :-/